# Using call on a jquery function for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, call

I have the following code what it does is, it inserts after a div with a specific id attribute when clicked on a button. and it increments a counter that is used to specify the div that it will be inserted after.

It all works, but what I want to know is? How can I change this code around, so that I can create an object with properties and then create a method that can be used to insert after, lastly I do the call to the specific jquery elements and the job gets done.

The reason for my enquiry is that i want to use this method on other objects that follows the same principles but has different object properties, so I can use a single method to call different objects with different properties and make the call to insert after different divs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

counter = 0;
$("#addMeasurement").on("click", function() {++counter;
    //create variables for insert after
    var container = '<div id="measurement_container' + counter + '" class="col-12 object">'
    var icon = '<span id="measurement_icon' + counter + '" class="flaticon-glass-of-water-with-drop" title="Measurement"></span>';
    var info_span = '<span id="measurement_info' + counter + '" class="">';
    var info_mT = '<input class="toTop" type="text" name="measurementType' + counter + '" id="measurementType' + counter + '" placeholder="Measurement" size="10">';
    var info_mA = '<input class="toTop" style="margin-left:90px;" type="text" name="measurementAbbr' + counter + '" id="measurementAbbr' + counter + '" placeholder="Abbr" size="3">';
    var info_mTi = '<input class="toTop" style="margin-top:25px;" type="text" name="measurementTitle' + counter + '" id="measurementTitle' + counter + '" placeholder="Name" size="10"> ';
    var info_mD = '<input class="toTop"  style="margin-top:25px; margin-left:90px; width:3.5em;" type="number" name="measurementDescimalPlaces' + counter + '" id="measurementDescimalPlaces' + counter + '" min="0" max="4" title="Descimal points" placeholder=".DP">';

    $(container + icon + info_span + info_mT + info_mA + info_mTi + info_mD + '</span>' + '</div>').insertAfter("#measurement_container" + (-1 + counter));

});
});
```

I want to have something like this (I omitted some of the properties in the object for easier readability).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 0;

var measurement_object = {
container : '<div id="measurement_container' + counter + '" 

class="col-12 object">',    
icon: '<span id="measurement_icon' + counter + '" class="flaticon-glass-

of-water-with-drop" title="Measurement"></span>'
}

function duplicate_object(el){
$(this).insertAfter(el);
}

$("#addMeasurement").on("click", function(){
duplicate_object.call(duplicate_object,"#measurement_container0");
});
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zef9x518/

Answer (score 0):

Honestly if you're inserting that much HTML with your JS, I'd take a step back and consider other options. It's a code smell that usually means you're approaching something in the wrong manner.

That being said, there's really no need to create a factory for a function this simple. Here's the core functionality of that function. I'm abbreviating the building of the element for the sake of time:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  
  $('#addMeasurement').on('click', function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    
    // This should be a class, since you're using it more than once.
    $(div).insertAfter('#measurement_container');
    
    count++;
  });
  
  $('.other-element').on('click', function() {
    console.log(count); // Outputs # of elements added
  });
});
```

Describe what you actually want to do on the page, and I can help a little more.

Comment: I want to write something like Obj = {}  function insert_after(param){} and then call that function something like insert_after.call(to my jquery element where i ant to insert the obj).  I have looked at your code and it does look promising. my only question is that if I createElement ('div') how do I give that div specific id's .  I have divs with inputs when I click plus I want to duplicate that div with the input but give them id's  of divname+1

Comment: You'd just do `div.className = 'class'` or `div.id = 'id'`. You can create a basic class [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/p06qrgfo/).